# Lisp using And in a Cond statement

Tags: lisp

having a little trouble correctly using "cond" in conjunction with "and" in one of my functions:

```
(cond (and (find 'hello actionsems)
        (find 'formal actionsems))
        (print "Chatterbot: Hello, how are you?")
    (and (find 'hello actionsems)
        (find 'informal actionsems))
        (print "Chatterbot: Hey, how's it going?")
    )
```

I am told that I am "attempting to take unbound variable "AND". Could someone point out where in the syntax I made a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `COND` macro takes a list of conditions and evaluate them in turn. The actual syntax from [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm) is:

```
Syntax:
cond {clause}* => result*

clause::= (test-form form*) 

Arguments and Values:
test-form---a form.
forms---an implicit progn.
results---the values of the forms in the first clause whose test-form yields true, or the primary value of the test-form if there are no forms in that clause, or else nil if no test-form yields true.
```

Taking that, your condition evaluation should look something like below:

```
(cond ((and (find 'hello actionsems)
            (find 'formal actionsems))
       (print "Chatterbot: Hello, how are you?"))
      ((and (find 'hello actionsems)
            (find 'infomal actionsems))
       (print "Chatterbot: Hey, how's it going?")))
```